# "Developers with cahuna's only" - is the apostrophe appropriate?

Tags: grammatical-number

I have the following sentence I've just seen, but I am pretty sure there should be no apostrophe on cahunas.

> developers with cahuna's only need apply.

Any ideas, I think it should be:

> developers with cahunas only need apply.

Comment: What the heck are *cahunas*? Do they mean *cojones*?

Comment: @choster I have no idea! It could be changed for any word I guess in this instance. Guessing he meant this: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cahunas

Comment: "Kahuna was the Hawaiian title for a shaman"

Comment: I'm guessing "cojones + kahuna" (wizard/boss testicles?) for some reason. I'd say no apostrophe, but the word order seems wrong in general.

Comment: Is that a specific technology? Are they discriminating based on gender, or are they looking for a certain [dare and do](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Hopper_%28DDG-70%29#Coat_of_Arms) attitude?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No apostrophe is needed there. Assuming "cahuna" is a thing, then it could read

> Only developers with cahunas need apply.

The apostrophe would only be required to show letters have been removed e.g. "Don't" or to show possession. E.g. "Look at John's cahunas"

Comment: This is correct.  Just to elaborate for others, the "thing" you speak of is, in fact, as Andreas Spaeth mentioned in his answer, "balls".  I have only ever heard "cahunas" used in referring to "balls", in slang expressions referring to one's bravery.  Based on the comments to the OP's question, I have no idea if cahunas is spelled correctly, but you can tell from the context in the question that only developers with some serious balls should be applying :)